# Erro when running OpenGL projet under Ubuntu 10.04

Tags: qt, opengl, ubuntu-10.04

I downloaded QtSDK from website and installed on my computer, my OS is Ubuntu 10.04.

When I compile a project of OpenGL, there is an error "GL/gl.h no such file or directory".

but when I compile the projet under windows, it works. Why?

Who can resolve this problem for me?

Comment: Do you have a "GL/gl.h" in Ubuntu?  It probably works in Windows because MinGW comes with it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to install the OpenGL development files. In Ubuntu they're in the package `libgl1-mesa-dev`. You'll also want to install `libglu1-mesa-dev`.

```
sudo apt-get install libgl1-mesa-dev libglu1-mesa-dev
```

I recommend installing GLEW alongside, since you'll jump the extension hoops to get OpenGL-3 functionality.

**Edit**

Here's how to get GLEW in Ubuntu (from the comments):

```
sudo apt-get install libglew-dev
```

Comment: Could you please say how to "install GLEW alongside"?

Comment: @ClareMacrae: Download the version matching your compiler from http://glew.sf.net, read the documentation, place the .lib files at some central place, add the path to where it's located in the compiler/linker's search path (same with the header) and add GLEW to the project requisites. Working with 3rd party libraries is basic programmer knowledge. If you don't know how to do it already, now is the time to learn it.

Comment: Thanks very much. Yes, I know how to use 3rd party libraries, but having recently discovered the beautiful simplicity of apt-get, I was thinking there might be a more streamlined way.

Comment: @ClareMacrae: Well then it gets really simply: `apt-get install libglew-dev` and you're done. But remember, not everbody uses a Debian based Linux and in some situations it might be worth to ship with a bundeled version of the library.

Comment: Ah brilliant. This worked for me. And as this question is specifically about Ubuntu, this command should be fine, I think, alongside the apt-get line in your answer!